Type 'FetchData[]' is not assignable to type 'string' (Ionic React Typescript)
The response.body is a base64 string of a file. How can I save it into a String variable?

fetchCustom(store.apiURL, {
            trtyp: 'file_download',
            seskey: store.userSessionKey,
            id: item.iddoc
        }).then(response => {
            const data = response.body as FetchData[];
            console.log('gotten base64', data);

            let base64File:string = data;
            
            Filesystem.writeFile({
                path: "filename.txt",
                data: base64File, //"base64 data",
                directory: Directory.Documents,
            }).then(response => {
            
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('error a', error.message);
            });
        
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error b', error.message);
        });

This is my FetchData definition
export type FetchData = {
  [key: string]: any
};


If your entire body data is a base 64 string then shouldn't you have const data = response.body as string  ?

I get: Conversion of type 'FetchBody' to type 'string' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
Type 'FetchData[]' is not comparable to type 'string'

this has nothing to do with ionic but a general js question.

If your response body is an array of objects, you can't just write it to a file as a string, and the error message is extremely clear on exactly what the problem is. If your response.body is actually a string, why are you telling the compiler it's an array of objects? What happens if you just remove that cast? I can't even tell what the question you are trying to ask is.

It looks like you're trying to assign an array of type FetchData[] to a string variable base64File, which is causing the TypeScript error.
If response.body is indeed a Base64 encoded string as part of a larger structure within FetchData[], you should first access the specific property of each FetchData item that holds the Base64 string. For instance, if each FetchData item has a property base64, you might need to extract this property from the array, or if you're only interested in the first item (assuming the API always returns only one item with the file data), you can do:
fetchCustom(store.apiURL, {
    trtyp: 'file_download',
    seskey: store.userSessionKey,
    id: item.iddoc
}).then(response => {
    // Assuming 'base64' is the property containing the Base64 string
    // and you are expecting only one item in the array.
    const base64File: string = response.body[0].base64;

    console.log('gotten base64', base64File);

    Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: "filename.txt",
        data: base64File, // Use the extracted Base64 string
        directory: Directory.Documents,
    }).then(response => {
        console.log('File written', response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error writing file', error.message);
    });

}).catch(error => {
    console.log('error fetching data', error.message);
});

Please adjust the property name base64 to whatever is appropriate according to the actual structure of the objects in your FetchData[] array. Also, ensure that you have proper error handling in case the array is empty or the property does not exist.
Hope this will work for you.

I get: Property '0' does not exist on type 'FetchData | FetchData[]
